# Cannot upload image to gcp from webhost server

Tags: php, file-upload, google-cloud-storage

```
$factory = (new Factory())
    ->withServiceAccount('./secret/firebase_credentials.json')
    ->withDisabledAutoDiscovery();

    $storage = $factory->createStorage();
    $defaultBucket = $storage->getBucket(); 
$uploadOptions = array_filter([
            'name' => $target,
            'predefinedAcl' => 'publicRead'
        ]);
        $uploadedFile = $defaultBucket->upload(base64_decode($thum), $uploadOptions);
```

using the Kreait library i was able to add it to my php project and tested it with my project.
when i tried it out from my local machine i was able to upload the image into google cloud storage.

But when i put the same code onto the webhost and try out the same code as on my local machine, i get an error failed to connect to oauth2.googleapis.com port 443.

i dont know whether the webhosting companies dont allow communication with other servers.

This below is the error am getting

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to oauth2.googleapis.com port 443: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

Comment: Could you share the error message you are getting?

Comment: @JoséSoní i have added the error message

Comment: Don't think the hosting companies block that.
I found [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1749) Could you confirm if this is the behavior?